# What's the relation between xpos and iterator in C++

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Let's say `xpos` is the return object of `std::basic_string::find` of type `size_type`, we can use `xpos` to access chars in a `std::string` by `some_string[xpos]`, and `xpos` itself could be used to represent the index of a char in a string, we can also directly print a `xpos`

```
std::string s{"012345678902"};
auto res = s.find('2');
std::cout << s[res] << " at " << res << '\n';
>>>
2 at 2
```

We could also use an `iterator` to access items in a container with operator `*`, but
we can't directly print an `iterator` and we need to use `std::distance` to calculate the index. To my understanding, `xpos` and `iterator` are similar to some extent but definitely not the same thing. However, when I am using `std::basic_string::erase(iterator first, iterator last)`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase makes it clear that we need two `iterators` to remove all chars in the range `[first, last)`

```
std::string s{"012345678902"};
auto it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '0');
auto rit = std::find(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), '0');
s.erase(it, rit.base()-1);
std::cout << s << '\n';
>>>
02
```

This works as expected. But when I use two `xpos` to replace `it` and `rit` above

```
std::string s{"012345678902"};
s.erase(s.find('0'), s.find_last_of('0'));
std::cout << s << '\n';
>>>
02
```

This code works as good as the `iterator` version. This confused me, since `xpos` and `iterator` are not identical, why `xpos` could be used perfectly to replace `iterator` in the function `std::basic_string::erase(iterator first, iterator last)`? What's exactly the relation between `xpos` and `iterator`?

Comment: because it is not that overload

Comment: your example just work correct because `s.find('0')==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no relation between `xpos` and `iterator` in those 2 calls. You're just calling a different overload of [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), specifically:

```
constexpr basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

Note that you *appear* to be getting the same results because the first argument in

```
s.erase(s.find('0'), s.find_last_of('0'));
```

is actually the 0th position, since the 0th index is the character `'0'`.

In general, passing an `xpos` to the second argument of this overload doesn't make sense, because it expects a "count", not a "position". If you want to actually erase everything between the first and last `'0'`, you would write something like:

```
auto xp = s.find('0'); 
s.erase(xp, s.find_last_of('0') - xp);
```